# Scaling button background images and resizing window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, button, graphics, scaling

Working on the design of a new WPF control which needs to display well on a 7 inch tablet and a large 20-30 inch monitor and anywhere in between.

I will have panel of buttons in the control which will have Icons to represent their actions and this panel can be changed depending on configuration and system state.

In all i think there are around 40 potential icons.

I initially assumed vector graphic files would be supported (.SVG Extension) but this isnt the case.

Having a large image file which looks good on a large monitor looks bad when the control is on the 7 inch tablet and the same holds true for a small image which looks good when scaled up to the large monitor.

An average size image only looks average on everything.

How do i best deal with scaling the images so that it looks best at both the small tablet and the large monitor?

This is the basics of how im displaying the images.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="PngImage" Source="C:\Images\acid.png"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />            
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{StaticResource PngImage}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: recognize current environment on startup and then use appropriate images: small for small screen, large for large

Comment: Normally for web, 3 separate sets are used, tiny / small / big. You can use same concept.

Comment: First u can try using `ViewBox` to contain your `Image`.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to convert SVG files to XAML paths using the Microsoft XPS printer driver.

There's a link [here](https://benpittoors.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/convert-svg-to-xaml/) for the process. It's a bit convoluted but if you don't have a bunch of files to convert this is probably the easiest.

If you need to do it in bulk there are a couple of converters out there.